# Scala - How to convert Spark DataFrame to Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, tuples, pivot

How to conver Spark DataFrame to Map like below : I want to convert into Map and then Json. Pivot didn't worked to reshape the cplumn so 
Any help will be appreciated to convert as a Map like below.

Input DataFrame :

```
        +-----+-----+-------+--------------------+
        |col1 |col2 |object | values             |
        +-------------------+--------------------+
        |one  | two | main  |[101 -> A, 202 -> B]|
        +-------------------+--------------------+

        Expected Output DataFrame :
        +-----+-----+-------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        |col1 |col2 |object | values             | newMap                                                                 |
        +-----+-----+-------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
        |one  | two |main   |[101 -> A, 202 -> B]|[col1 -> one, col2 -> two, object -> main, main -> [101 -> A, 202 -> B]]|
        +-----+-----+-------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

tried like below, but no success :

```
    val toMap = udf((col1: String, col2: String, object: String, values: Map[String, String])) => {
    col1.zip(values).toMap // need help for logic
    // col1 -> col1_value, col2 -> col2_values, object -> object_value, object_value -> [values_of_Col_Values].toMap
  })

    df.withColumn("newMap", toMap($"col1", $"col2", $"object", $"values"))
    I am stuck to format the code properly and get the output, please help either in Scala or Spark.
```

Comment: Maybe, "Struct" can be used instead of "Map"? Code will be quite simple in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's quit straight forward. Apparently the **precondition** is, *you must have all the columns with same type* otherwise you will get spark error.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = Seq(("Foo", "L", "10"), ("Boo", "XL", "20"))
        .toDF("brand", "size", "sales")

//Prepare your map columns.Bit of nasty iteration work is required
  var preCol: Column = null
  var counter = 1
  val size = df.schema.fields.length
  val mapColumns = df.schema.flatMap { field =>

  val res = if (counter == size)
          Seq(preCol, col(field.name))
        else
          Seq(lit(field.name), col(field.name))

 //assign the current field name for tracking and increment the counter by 1
   preCol = col(field.name)
   counter += 1

   res
  }

df.withColumn("new", map(mapColumns: _*)).show(false)
```

**Result**

```
+-----+----+-----+---------------------------------------+
|brand|size|sales|new                                    |
+-----+----+-----+---------------------------------------+
|Foo  |L   |10   |Map(brand -> Foo, size -> L, L -> 10)  |
|Boo  |XL  |20   |Map(brand -> Boo, size -> XL, XL -> 20)|
+-----+----+-----+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Balaji, Please have a look on output, for last Map, key should be value of another column instead of Column_name. please suggest. Output : [col1 -> one, col2 -> two, object -> main, main -> [101 -> A, 202 -> B]]

Comment: @Lucky got your point. let me update my answer. In my output , 
Map(brand -> Foo, size -> L, L -> 10). 
Is this expected ?

Comment: Thanks Balaji for the right approach, but can you please clear, How to specify the col_name -> col_value for  last key->condition, because column sequence can be any number :   "L -> 10 "

Comment: @Lucky i did not completely understand your query. can you be bit more elaborate ?

Comment: Hi @Balaji, I wanted to understand that how to provide the column Sequence/Name to Create Map, If I want to do the same Operation for last 6 columns out of total 10 Columns in Raw DataFrame. and for which column key should be value of another column as per your last updated Answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211214/discussion-between-balaji-reddy-and-lucky).